# wordpress slow query for postmeta

Tags: mysql, wordpress

These are the 2 queries that are taking almost 2 mins for my website to load

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM wp8k_posts
LEFT JOIN wp8k_postmeta ON (wp8k_posts.ID = wp8k_postmeta.post_id
                            AND wp8k_postmeta.meta_key = 'rate')
LEFT JOIN wp8k_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp8k_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (wp8k_postmeta.post_id IS NULL
       OR mt1.meta_key = 'rate')
  AND wp8k_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp8k_posts.post_status = 'publish'
       OR wp8k_posts.post_status = 'private')
```

and the other one is

```
SELECT wp8k_posts.ID
FROM wp8k_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp8k_postmeta ON (wp8k_posts.ID = wp8k_postmeta.post_id
                            AND wp8k_postmeta.meta_key = 'rate')
LEFT JOIN wp8k_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp8k_posts.ID = mt1.post_id)
WHERE 1 = 1
  AND (wp8k_postmeta.post_id IS NULL
       OR mt1.meta_key = 'rate')
  AND wp8k_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp8k_posts.post_status = 'publish'
       OR wp8k_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY wp8k_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp8k_postmeta.meta_value + 0 DESC
LIMIT 32, 16
```

Is there any way to make it not take almost 2 mins for my site to load because of these queries.

Comment: Is the only difference:  GROUP BY + ORDER BY + LIMIT ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be equivalent to your query:

```
SELECT  p.ID
    FROM  wp8k_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN  wp8k_postmeta AS a  ON p.ID = a.post_id
                                  AND a.meta_key = 'rate' 
    LEFT JOIN  wp8k_postmeta AS b  ON p.ID = b.post_id
    WHERE  ( a.post_id IS NULL
              OR  b.meta_key = 'rate' 
           )
      AND  p.post_type = 'post'
      AND  p.post_status IN ( 'publish', 'private' )
    GROUP BY  p.ID
    ORDER BY  a.meta_value+0 DESC
    LIMIT  32, 16
```

The confusing thing is that both LEFT JOINs seem to be looking for the same column, but in different ways:

```
    ON ...   a.meta_key = 'rate' 
    WHERE  ( a.post_id IS NULL
         OR  b.meta_key = 'rate' )
```

But more confusing is that you are demanding that `a` be missing, yet doing `ORDER BY a.meta_value+0`.  So, that will always be NULL, so the `ORDER BY` can be removed.  (Or fix the rest of the query.)  Since that was the only use for `a`, the entire `LEFT JOIN a` can be removed.

```
SELECT  p.ID
    FROM  wp8k_posts AS p
    WHERE  p.post_type = 'post'
      AND  p.post_status IN ( 'publish', 'private' )
    GROUP BY  p.ID
    LIMIT  32, 16
```

The query does not use `b` at all, so that LEFT JOIN can be total removed.

The result is a LIMIT without an ORDER BY, which usually does not make sense.

This should give the same results, except that it may be a different 16 rows.  And it should be as fast because, I think, there is an index starting with `(post_type, post_status)`.

**Solution?**

You apparently wanted to do something with `rate`.

- Don't join twice to postmeta looking for the same "rate".
- Don't use `LEFT` unless you are expecting to have some rows without a rate being specified.
- If you only want rows with a "rate", then postmeta needs some improved indexes.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta